# CodeIgniter 2 no longer able to use PATH_INFO after modifying .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, codeigniter-2, pathinfo

I'm brand new to CI and I'm trying to remove the annoying "index.php" from the URLs. This is the .htaccess I'm using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

As you can see, I have to use `QUERY_STRING` to make the new URL work (note the question mark after index.php). When I try to use `PATH_INFO` (i.e. without the question mark), I only get `No input file specified` error.

This is fine, and I'm OK with using `QUERY_STRING` if I have to, but I don't understand the problem because I was using `PATH_INFO` just fine before I started playing with the rewrite - i.e. the default of "example.com/index.php/controller/function" was working, and that uses PATH_INFO AFAIK.

Does anyone know why the htaccess breaks PATH_INFO in my example? Sorry for the stupid question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine   on
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule     .* index.php/%{REQUEST_URI}   [L]
```

The rewrite rules above seem to work fine for an app that I'm currently working on... they pass the correct GET requests along with the proper PATH_INFO values.